# List All Posts From A WordPress Site On A PHP Page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Edit:The problem is the script timeout.

Up to WordPress version 3.2.1 I used this code on a page called 'list.php' in the root of my site. When I go to this page, permalinks to all the posts I posted on my site show up.

Once I installed WordPress 3.5.1 this code stopped working. How could we fix it?

```
<?php
    require_once('wp-config.php');
    require_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=1');
    foreach($myposts as $post){
        echo trim(the_permalink())."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you attempted altering `numberposts` to `posts_per_page`?

Comment: I did it doesn't work.

Comment: But the problem was the script timeout, thought i didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried using `WP_Query` and the call of `wp-load.php` at the beginning of your php file? The code will look like this:

```
<?php


header('Content-Type: text/html; charset: UTF-8');
require( '../../../../wp-load.php' );

$my_query = new WP_Query('numberposts=-1&offset=1'); 


if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 

echo trim(the_permalink())."<br>";

endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Where `../../....../` is the path to your `wp-load.php` file.

Comment: I'd suggest using an absolute path. Unrelated but nice read: [wp-load, I'll find you!](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/wp-load-php-i-will-find-you/)